# multiple long running operations in same async block or separate blocks

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

Is there any difference between writing 2 `async{}.await()` blocks one below another, versus putting all code in singe `async{}.await()` block?

Example 1:

```
async(CommonPool) {
   //long running code 1
}.await()
async(CommonPool) {
   //long running code 2
}.await()
```

Example 2:

```
async(CommonPool) {
   //long running code 1
   //long running code 2
}.await()
```

Which is better, it looks like its the same, just curious....

Note: `//long running code 1` and `//long running code 2` need to run consecutively

Edit1: 
I'm asking because my project is full of code from `Example 1` for some reason :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your examples if both `async` coroutine builders don't return some data (in your example it seems so). In both cases `long running code 1` and `long running code 2` will execute consecutively. The second case has less code though and more readable.

If you want to execute two consecutive non `suspend` operations in background(worker) thread you can use [`withContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) builder function:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // long running non-suspend code 1, 
    // long running non-suspend code 2
}
```

Using [`Dispatchers.IO`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) the code execution is switched to background thread.

For calling `suspend` functions you can use [`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) coroutine builder:

```
scope.launch {
    // long running suspend code 1
    // long running suspend code 2
}
```

[`async`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) coroutine builder is mainly used to launch a coroutine and get some result from it in the future.